# How to avoid code repetition calling recursive Makefiles?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to simplify a Makefile of the following form in order to avoid code repetition:

```
dir1/foo:
    make -C dir1 foo

dir1/bar:
    make -C dir1 bar

dir2/baz:
    make -C dir2 baz

...

clean: 
    make -C dir1 clean
    make -C dir2 clean
    ...
```

I imagine I could specify only:

```
MY_TARGETS=dir1/foo dir1/bar dir2/baz ...
```

And than have some **general rules** to derive targets, as presented in the Makefile above.

Comment: Don't use recursive Makefiles. See [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf).

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Targets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given us much information. Recursive Make can be a good solution, if your main makefile is as simple as your example (which I doubt).

You could do this:

```
%:
    $(MAKE) -C $(dir $@) $(notdir $@)

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C dir1 clean
    $(MAKE) -C dir2 clean
    ...
```

If that `clean` recipe is too long, you can simplify it:

```
DIRS := dir1 dir2 ...

clean:
    @for x in $(DIRS); do $(MAKE) -C $$x clean; done
```

Or if you don't like having that `DIRS` list there, you could have Make generate it, depending on whether you want to `make clean` in *all* subdirectories, or all that match the `dir*` pattern, or... you haven't given us enough information.